# Get pixel from Pixmap with orthogrpahic camera in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an ortographic camera with zoom and in the center of camera I have a texture.

I fixed my world coordinates with:

```
height = 20;
float ppu = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / height;
width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / ppu;
camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
```

When the user touchdown in the image I want to retrieve the color pixel where the user clicked. So in TouchDown event I have:

```
Vector3 worldCoordinate =camera.unproject(new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0));
float newX = worldCoordinate.x;
float newY = worldCoordinate.y;
Pixmap source = img.getPixmap();
int color = source.getPixel(newX, newY);
```

The problem is that getPixel method expect an integer instead of float, moreover the size of my texture inside the camera is width=106.6, height = 80 and the texture has a dimension of 3436(width), 2409(height). I don't know how to map the camera coordinates to object cordinates in order to get the exact pixel where user clicked.

Any advice?
Thanks.